# .htaccess rewrite regex: match anything but "index"

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess

I'm trying to create a rule used in a .htaccess file to match **anything but** a particular string, in this case: `index`.

I thought that it should be possible to match this special string first and use `[L]` but that's not working,
and it should be possible using the following regex, but it causes a 500 error.

I want to match:

- pagename1
- pagename2/whatever
- pagename3/234/whatever
- about
- contact-us
- (etc)

but not

- index/123
- index/124/whatever

(BTW "index" is the name of a file with no extension, not my choice, this is a work thing)

```
^(?!index)[\w/\-]+
```

I assume that apache's implementation of regex doesn't cope with the `(?!xxx)` rule.

Any help/suggestions will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use `RewriteCond`s to do this, for example:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^index
RewriteRule (.*) index.php?what=$1
```

That will rewrite every URL which doesn't start by index. If you want it to avoid it anywhere in the URL, remove the `^`

Comment: I could only get this to work by using "!index" instead of "!^index".  (And yes, "index" was a the beginning of the request string, as in jezmck's question above).  Any thoughts as to why this might be the case?

Comment: Solved it.  Even if you're working in a subdirectory, using "RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}" uses the entire request URI, so you've got to include the www path to the current directory.  In my case, this means I used: "RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/r/index$" (the .htaccess file I'm working in is in the 'r' directory).

Answer (score 4):

(Please read the comments. I doubt it and I've never encountered problems, while it gives one much cleaner `.htaccess` files, but: using `RewriteCond` **might** be preferred over using `RewriteRule` with a dash, due to how [rulesets are processed](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html#InternalRuleset)?)

Just use RewriteRule as follows, to *not* rewrite (the dash), and stop subsequent rewriting (the `[L]`) for anything that starts with `index/`:

```
# Do not rewrite anything that starts with index/
RewriteRule ^index/ - [L]
```

After this, do any rewriting you like.

Or maybe even limit some more first:

```
# Do not rewrite files, directories or symbolic links 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR] 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR] 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l 
RewriteRule . - [L]
```

Comment: Ah, that may well be the answer I was looking for, I didn't know about `-` in .htaccess

Comment: Conds are safer. If you have another rule matching index later on things could get weird. [L] is not the last pass ever, just terminates the current pass, there are various cases where the request passes more than one time through the rules.

Comment: @Vinko, multiple passes are good to keep in mind indeed. But how would a RewriteCond (especially a negative RewriteCond) not be subject to weird matches during another pass then?

Answer (score 1):

Apache used three different regular expression implementations. The first was System V8, since Apache 1.3 they used POSIX ERE and since Apache 2 they use PCRE. And only PCRE supports look-ahead assertions. So you need Apache 2 to use that rule.

But now to your question. If you use this rule:

```
RewriteRule ^index/ - [L]
```

anything that starts with `/index/` should be catched by this rule and no further rule should be applied.

But if that doesn’t work, try this:

```
RewriteRule !^index/ …
```

Again, this rule will be applied on any request that’s URL path doesn’t start with `/index/`.

And if you want to capture anything from the URL, use a `RewriteCond` condition to test either the full URL path itself (`%{REQUEST_URI}`) or just the match of one of your pattern groups:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index/
RewriteRule (.*) …
# or
RewriteCond $1 !^index$
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/(.*) …
```